# Daemon threads - When does a python app finish running?

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, daemon, exit

I found this in the python documentation.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.daemon

> The entire Python program exits when no alive non-daemon threads are
> left.

Does this mean that a python application terminates when there are literally **only daemon threads** left? Or am I misunderstanding

```
import threading
import time

def daemonThread():
    while True:
        print("Sending Out Heartbeat Signal")
        time.sleep(2)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
        daemonThread = threading.Thread(target=daemonThread)
        daemonThread.daemon = True
        daemonThread.start()
        print('finish')
```

Output:

```
Sending Out Heartbeat Signal
finish
```

In this example, my program quickly ends up ignoring the daemon thread *even when it has an infinite loop*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Daemon threads do not stop a Python program running

So yes, when all that is left is daemon threads, the program stops.

It hasn't ignored the daemon thread, it has simply killed it, as expected.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html

> A thread can be flagged as a “daemon thread”. The significance of this
> flag is that the entire Python program exits when only daemon threads
> are left. The initial value is inherited from the creating thread. The
> flag can be set through the daemon property or the daemon constructor
> argument.
>
> Note Daemon threads are abruptly stopped at shutdown. Their resources
> (such as open files, database transactions, etc.) may not be released
> properly. If you want your threads to stop gracefully, make them
> non-daemonic and use a suitable signalling mechanism such as an Event.

#### Use daemon threads for things you want to last as long as the non-daemon part of your program is running

... but be unceremoniously killed as soon as it is over.

Comment: hi @Eureka, thank you very much, +1, nice of you to quote me the recent official documentation.